# Can someone help with a rewrite rule for IIS?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, isapi

I am using Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite and have entered the following Rewrite Rule:

`RewriteRule /([^/?.]+) /MemberPages/OrderSupplies.aspx\?Name=$1 [NC,L]`

However, I have little regex knowledge, and this rule almost works. However, here is my situation:

I want my visitors to be able to enter the following on the URL:

`http://www.somedomain.com/UserName`

and when they do, they get redirected to:

`http://www.somedomain.com/MemberPages/OrderSupplies.aspx`

The above rule, works, **but I do not want** the rule to fire if the `UserName` is a file.

For example the rule should NOT fire if the following is entered:

```
http://www.somedomain.com/Default.aspx  
http://www.somedomain.com/login.aspx  
http://www.somedomain.com/otherpage.aspx
```

The rule above strips out the '`.`' but I want to ignore any filenames, or any text with a '`.`'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/?.]+)$ MemberPages/OrderSupplies.aspx?Name=$1 [NC,L]
```

I'm not sure if you can specify the preceding / after the hostname or not in mod_rewrite. Also, you don't need to escape the ? in the replace string from what I know. But in any case if that doesn't work, try it the way you had it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/?.]+)$ /MemberPages/OrderSupplies.aspx\?Name=$1 [NC,L]
```

So the general ^([^/?.]+)$ pattern states that from begin to end there can not be any ? or . or / characters.